# Set application that displays desktop

Tags: 15.10, desktop-environments

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 15.10 by default it comes with `caja` file manager.
I've installed `pcmanfm` and removed `caja` from the system.

Now the files on desktop are not shown, but they are present in relevant folder when opened by file manager.

Can I get directions on how to get desktop displayed while using `pcmanfm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run it with `--desktop` to manage the desktop.

```
pcmanfm --desktop
```

For more info see: `man pcmanfm`. You can add it to startup applications or just take nautilus example below:

```
$ more /etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Files
Exec=nautilus -n
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
AutostartCondition=GSettings org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons
NoDisplay=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus
```

Comment: Well that did the trick. Although I've started this question because it seemed to me unnatural to put system  commands into user related scripts. But it seems that there is no other way.

Comment: @Dimitry, updated answer if you want a global setup

Answer (score 0):

The files on the desktop are shown by caja. Most desktops show the desktop using a file manager, Unity uses Nautilus, Windows uses Explorer, etc.

According this this: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=180262 , there is no easy solution.

Comment: Well, at least these days it doesn't die horribly if you try doing that. (At least for me.)